# Signed fulltime offer to start after my upcoming internship ends; should I keep this secret from the internship?

Tags: job-offer, internship

I have recently signed a summer internship at company A, however I also signed a full time contract at company B that starts half a month after the internship with A ends.

What I am wondering about is if I should keep this secret for company A during this summer, or if it’s fine to tell them if I’m asked about e.g. future positions.

Keep in mind that I am considering working full time at company A later in my career (after 3+ years) if I get a good impression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I am wondering about is if I should keep this secret for company A during this summer, or if it’s fine to tell them if I’m asked about e.g. future positions.

What advantage is there for you to keep it a secret? You've got a full time position *confirmed* after the internship with company A finishes, which is great. If they ask you about future positions, then just tell them about your confirmed full time position with company B, but state that you'll definitely bear them in mind in the future if you're looking for other work.

Comment: It seems as if OP is worried about repercussions and doesn't want company A to think bad of them after taking another full time, that's no theirs. You don't know where you'll be in "3+" years from now @abc123 so worry about that bridge when it arrives. Simply treat company A with respect and they will respect you.

Comment: @RichB If you're worried about repercussions from being honest that you have a full time job lined up after your internship, and those worries prove to be well founded, it's certainly not a place I'd recommend for long term employment.

Answer (score 3):

> What I am wondering about is if I should keep this secret for company A during this summer, or if it’s fine to tell them if I’m asked about e.g. future positions.

Tell that only if they ask. There is a chance, they may not ask as well. So no! Do not keep it as a secret but at the same time you do not have to bring it up on your own.

> Keep in mind that I am considering working fulltime at company A later in my career (after 3+ years) if I get a good impression.

This is a very vague information which will not help anything right now. 3 years is a long term with lot of ifs. Just think about the situation now and make the right decision.